# Changing date format to isodate using regular expression

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to change a date format from this:

```
30. Jan 2008 
28. Dec 2010
```

to this (isodate):

```
2008-01-30
2010-12-28
```

using a regular expression? The language I am working in is JS.

Thanks.

Comment: use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) Or do it with `split()`. Go ahead and try something, and post the code here if it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally always better to parse your date into parts that can be passed to `new Date` so that you'd get a date object you can work with

Something like

```js
var date   = "30. Jan 2008";

var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var parts  = date.split(' ').map(x=>x.replace('.',''));
var dObj   = new Date(parts[2], months.indexOf(parts[1]), parts[0]);
var zero   = (x) => x < 9 ? '0' + x : x;
var parsed = dObj.getFullYear() + '-' + zero(dObj.getMonth()+1) + '-' + dObj.getDate();

console.log(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any regular expression for this. If the pattern of input dateString is fixed. Then it can be done this way:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Date convert</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var dateString = "30. Jan 2008";
    var day = dateString.substring(0,2);
    var month = dateString.substring(4,7);
    var year = dateString.substring(8, dateString.length);
    var monthNameToNumberObj = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04", "May": "05", "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08", "Sep": "09", "Oct": "10", "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12"};
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = year+"-"+monthNameToNumberObj[month]+"-"+day;
    
}
</script>
```

[Please consider that I am assuming that Year will always will be in 4 digit, days will be in 2 digit. If they are worrying then you need to use split function to extract day, month and year]